# Python Kivy not showing window and saying:

Tags: python, kivy

I just started learning Kivy. I keep getting this in the terminal.

```
/bin/python3 /home/maheswar/basics/Kivy.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/maheswar/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-03-14_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/maheswar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
```

By the way, I am using Linux (Ubuntu).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's completely normal, those are information to inform you kivy start running. but about:

> Kivy not showing window

if you use a code like below you can see the kivy window.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MaiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="das")

MaiApp().run()
```

Comment: I am so sorry. I am new to this. Thank you so much!!